# class indexer design to access all array in a class

Tags: c#, oop, c#-6.0

I have a scenario where I need to store a list of values, eg: id, name, department, mobile number, etc

The current approach I use is to store in DataTable, access through row numbers and do modifications.

Is there a way where I could create a class containing all this properties and access through indexers?

some thing like below

```
class Person
{
  public int[] id{get;set;}
  public string[] Name{get; set;}
  //your suggestion for indexer is required here
  public <some type> this[int index]
  {
   //get/set logic to retrieve/modify a users input ->so that the following is achieved
   //some thing like Person P=new Person(); now I should be able to do modifications like P[0].Name="New Name" or should retrieve data like P[0].Name,P[0].Id could be done
  }    
}
```

Note: All arrays will have same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an another class having a list of Person and an indexer that return the instance of person.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      Persons pp=new Persons();
      Person p=new Person() { id=1, Name="test"};
      Person p1=new Person() { id=2, Name="test1"};
      pp.PersonsList.Add(p);
      pp.PersonsList.Add(p1);

      pp[1]=new Person(){id=3,Name="tye"};
      Console.WriteLine(pp[1].Name);
   }
 }


 class Person
 {

  public int id {get;set;}
  public string   Name {get; set;}

 }

 class Persons
 {
   public Persons()
   {
       PersonsList=new List<Person>();
   }
   public List<Person> PersonsList {get;set;}
   public Person this[int index]
   {
     get {  return PersonsList[index];  }
     set { 
         PersonsList[index].id=value.id;
         PersonsList[index].Name=value.Name;
         }
   }
 }
```

Working Code here... [Code link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0vAANJ)

Answer (score -1):

You may return an intermediate type. However I do not recommend doing that. Your "parallel array" approach often indicates a missing type and is considered as a code smell. I recommend you to create a class (or maybe a strict, depending on your use case), with an Id and a name property. And store instances of that class in an array or an other collection type.

If you go with the intermediate approach, you can do something like this

```
struct PersonEntry
{
    private readonly Person _person;
    private readonly int _index;

    public PersonEntry(Person person, int index)
    {
        _person = person;
        _index = index;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get => _person.id[ _index];
        set => _person.id[ _index] = value;
    }

    public int Name
    {
        get => _person.Name[ _index];
        set => _person.Name[ _index] = value;
    }
}

PersonEntry this[int index]
{
    get => new PersonEntry(this, index);
}
```

With this approach you can change the name and the id.

My recommend Solution is:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

Person[] persons;
```

Comment: c# 6.0 does not support named tuple.

Comment: @mukeshkudi oh. I thought they came in 6.0 I will change my answer.